# Distribute 10 infinite jobs over 4 threads in a load-balanced manner (Java)

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, threadpool

I have **10 calculation jobs** that take (near) **infinite time**. For example: calculate the next digit of PI, [solve](http://www.optaplanner.org/) an NP-hard constraint satisfaction problem, etc.

I have **4 threads** (so a thread pool with 4 threads on a machine with **8 cores**, so I have some cores left to **avoid live-locking the machine** and the process).

Using Java 8, how do distribute these 10 jobs across those 4 threads?

This is a bad idea:

```
ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
for (Job j : jobs) {
    es.submit(j);
}
```

because 4 jobs will start, but none will finish so job 5-10 will never start.

If I look after for example 10 minutes, I would expect that each job has run for about 4 minutes. After 20 minutes, each job has run for about 8 minutes, etc. What are the typical patterns to deal with this? (If needed, I can implement a way to pauze a calculation after a preset amount of time.)

Comment: For 10 simultaneous jobs, have 10 threads. The CPU will schedule them, so you don't need to attempt to copy the behaviour (poorly) in your own code. You seem to mistakenly think that if you create 4 threads on a 4-core CPU, that the CPU is "full". Well it's not.

Comment: It's non-blocking calculations (not web requests), no IO, so the CPU is full. So I need a way to have it only use 4 out of 8 cpu's and still handle infinite 10 jobs.

Comment: you can use containers to limit core usage

Comment: I 've got other threads in my process too (servlets threads to input/output calculation requests and intermediate responses). The container approach will still starve them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The task of distributing ten jobs between four threads and the task of utilizing only four CPUs (I use CPU here as a synonym of *core* for simplicity) by your ten jobs are a bit different.

**Four threads**

Limiting the threads number to four will not guarantee that they will stick to four CPUs and won't use the others. OS is allowed to shuffle your threads between all available CPUs as it likes. The only thing you can guarantee, is that your program won't be able to utilize more than 50% of all the CPU resources (given the fact that you have eight CPUs).

But it's unlikely that you'll manage to utilize those 50%. Despite the fact that your jobs are primarily CPU-oriented, chances are that they still need read from and write to memory from time to time. When a thread misses cache on such readings/writings and waits for data to be delivered to the processor, this processor put the thread on hold and can do some work in another thread. In your case, it will have nothing to do and just sit idle until the data arrives. So, it's likely that your CPUs will be underutilized.

If you decide to go with this approach, you need to break your jobs into small tasks and feed them to the executors, as @James Large said. You can either use `WorkStealingPool` with four threads (as @Alexey Soshin proposed), or create a pool with ten threads and use a `Semaphore` with four permits and fairness set to `true`. In the latter case, your threads must use loops, acquire permits at the beginning of every iteration and release them at the end. Each iteration will represent a small chunk of work.

**Four CPUs**

There're mechanisms to designate particular CPUs to work on your tasks.

On the process level in Linux you can use [special commands](http://linux.die.net/man/1/taskset) to bind your process to particular CPUs. That will allow you to create ten threads and let the OS do all the balancing on four CPUs.

On the threads level, you can try [Java Affinity library](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Java-Thread-Affinity) from OpenHFT. It allows to bind threads to CPUs right in your Java code. The problem is that ten threads cannot be devided between four CPUs without reminder, so it will be hard to balance them.

Comment: Good choice. There are many algorithms for using small tasks. The Java Fork/Join framework is one. I just happen to manage a scatter-gather service that would use small tasks also. Work-stealing is that once a Thread finishes with one task it can fetch another out of another Thread's queue that may be tied up with a long running task.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for WorkStealingPool:

```
static ExecutorService executor = Executors.newWorkStealingPool(4);
private static Map<Integer, AtomicInteger> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {


    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        executor.submit(new Worker(i))  ;
    }

    Thread.sleep(10000);
    System.out.println(map);
}

private static class Worker implements Runnable {
    private final int k;

    public Worker(int k) {
        this.k = k;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        map.putIfAbsent(k, new AtomicInteger(0));
        map.get(k).getAndIncrement();
        executor.submit(new Worker(this.k));

       // Also possible to resubmit current job
       //executor.submit(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: How does this limit it to 4 threads (so only 4 of my 8 cores)? I think this will spawn 10 threads, use all 8 cores and the `Thread.yield()` will just make sure no one starves.

Comment: If instead, I use a `Executors.newWorkStealingPool(4)` and remove the `while` loop from the job, replacing it with submit a new job for the next step calculation, this might work?

Comment: Absolutely, if you can preserve the states. I've updated the example.

Comment: Thanks. Any idea if it would be legal to submit the same `Worker` instance again?

Comment: It's possible, if you want to reduce GC. Added commented text to my answer to demonstrate. Still, that's a bit risky, if you have a lot of members, and need to reset some of them.

Answer (score 1):

I am somewhat bothered by the idea of a "Job that never finishes."  I would call it something else, like "long-running computation" or,...

If you've got ten of them, and you can only afford four threads to work on them, then your only choice is to break them into finite "sub-jobs" that *do* finish, and then write a scheduler that keeps feeding sub-jobs to the four available threads.

But that would be replicating most of what the threading system is supposed to do for you.

I would just make ten threads.  If you're running on a machine that only has four available cores to run the ten threads, the OS will automatically break your long running jobs into "sub-jobs" (i.e., time slices), and schedule them fairly on the four cores.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to execute 10 jobs in parallel - simply run 10 threads.

Change `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4)` to `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10)`.

Comment: My machine has 8 cores. I only want to spend 4 of them on these calculations (which never block on IO, so each one drains 100% of a CPU), so I can use the other cores to handle web requests, ssh logins, etc.

Comment: Can you do it simply setting processors affinity from outside the program, i.e. set the program to use only cores 1-4?

Comment: The web requests (which are handle on servlets threads, so not in those 4 calculation threads) are handled in the same process, for example a REST call to add calculations or to take intermediate results and send them back to clients.

Comment: If you can't use processor affinity you'll need to make your computations pauseable and implement some scheduling, i.e. make work which OS usually does itself.

Comment: Agreed - I was thinking that way too - suppose I have a way to pause the computations - what kind of scheduling patterns are there?

Comment: Many scheduling algorithms exist depending on the nature of the jobs. There are several books addressing this question, for example I read about it in The Design and Implementation of the FreeBSD Operating System by Marshall Kirk McKusick and George V. Neville-Neil.